# django-uWSGI-nginx deployment issue: No public access behind VPN and proxy

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, vpn, uwsgi

I am trying to deploy a django application with uWSGI & nginx.

I followed [this](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) tutorial to the end and everything seems to be working fine, but for accessing the app from an external IP.

I do not own a domain name yet so my relevant nginx settings look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "";
}
```

Also, I have disabled the firewall:

`iptables -S` gives:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Now the CentOs 6.7 machine I am deploying on, has no direct access to the internet as it is behind a proxy (i.e. I need to do `pip install django --http_proxy=myproxy.mynet:myport` for it to work).

Among other things I have tried to use proxy_pass in my nginx configuration. One attempt:

```
http {

  upstream corporate_proxy  {
      server myproxy.mynet:myport;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    rewrite_log on;
    location / {
          proxy_set_header Host "";
          proxy_pass http://corporate_proxy;
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, let me add that I cannot access the machine from outside the network either, as it is inside a VPN. So in order to ssh onto it, I first need to connect to the VPN (through FortiClient console).

It is not quite clear to me how all this VPN/proxying really works and how it affects the communication between nginx and external requests. Any solutions or ways to further troubleshoot more than welcome!

Comment: I think your configuration about proxy_pass is not correct. Please using uwsgi_pass because of you are using uwsgi to run django web

Comment: Thanks, but I am using it:. The part with proxy_pass was just a try, and I haven't shared my entire configuration file which includes: `   location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /path/to/your/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }`. As mentioned, the application is getting served normally and I can access it locally. I just cannot reach it from the outside internet.

Comment: You cannot access a server which is sitting behind a proxy from an external host. Proxies only allow the clients to access outside resources, not vice versa. Your external clients must log in to VPN to access your web application.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks, it would be very weird if that was to be the case. This is a web application developed for a big institute and they have assigned me this server particularly to deploy this application on the internet...

Comment: I don't know about your infrastructure but from what you write it looks impossible. There might be another interface that is open to the public. The reverse proxy feature of NginX (proxy_pass directive) has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Selcuk yes, admittedly using this was more out of desperation... I have already emailed them asking for potential further info I may need for deployment that they haven't supplied (all I have now is the vpn credentials and the outbound proxy and port). So, there is nothing more to do than wait for their reply you think?

Comment: Yes, they should let you know.